# How to use python in Wordpress if needed

Tags: wordpress

As the heading of the question; I just want to know whether it is possible to use python in Wordpress for a complete build of a web page. I have seen some answers but, they were not satisfactory and it is recommended to use python there?

Comment: Try this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/311479/python-in-wordpress-a-hello-world-implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want to know whether it is possible to use python in Wordpress for a complete build of a web page.

Yes, python should be installed onto your server. On most linux powered servers we have python by default.

However, shared hosting will allow you to run python inside wordpress. It is best to be on VPS then you can trigger python from wordpress using short codes.That will execute and display python script output on the page.

For further reading please follow the links below:

The trick is use the word press[source code] shortcut tag, as documented at

http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/